# Limiting Bucket Search using QueryBuilder field type in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, query-builder, buckets, sitecore8

In our Sitecore application, we have a template called NewsArticleSlide which renders a news article on a carousel slide. This template has a field called "News article" which contains the ID of the news article being rendered. The type of this field up to now has been droplink, which has been perfect for selecting a single item from a tree, and specifying what the root of that tree should be.

Now we've decided to contain all news articles in a single bucket called "News". The problem is that we can't now use droplink to select an item from the bucket, and no "droplink with search" field type exists.

QueryBuilder seems like the best fit as it enables us to select a single item from a bucket. However, when we initially run a search, everything in Sitecore is returned and we then have to filter by template to see only news articles.

What we want to do is pre-filter the search by specifying the starting point for the search, and limiting the search to only return items of a particular template. We assumed we could do this using parameters in the Source of the template field, but have had no success doing this.

Does anyone know how we can do this? Is QueryBuilder the right approach?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are asking here. Do you have the sample code of what you are having trouble with?

Comment: This is not a code question. We are designing Sitecore templates, and I am talking about the QueryBuilder field type in the Sitecore UI. We want users to be able to select a single item from a bucket using the QueryBuilder Field Type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by changing your `Droplink` field to a `Multilist with Search` field instead. [Here's a blog post](https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/sitecore-7-development-team/posts/2013/10/using-the-new-sitecore-7-field-types.aspx) showing you the options for restricting the values in the list from your bucket.

Now one key thing here is that this field type is a multi-select field, but you may only want to use it to select a single News Article. You can use a RegEx to force only one selection:

1. Find the item in the tree that represents the field (below the field section item below the template item)
2. Turn on **Standard fields** on the **View** ribbon
3. In the `Validation` field enter this RegEx: `^(\{[^}]+\}\|?){0,1}$`
4. In the `Validation Text` field enter a message, e.g. "**You may only select up to 1 item.**"

This will allow you to use a **Multilist with Search** field to select a single item within a bucket.

Comment: Thanks Mark, this definitely helps us achieve what we want. 
I do think the QueryBuilder field type should accept similar parameters in the Source field to be in any way useful. It felt counter-intuitive to use a multi list to select a single item, however validating with the regex you provided works a treat!